# Pixel Format conversion

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

What is the equivalent of `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format64bppPArgb` in `System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats` ? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you read and of the MSDN documentation on `PixelFormat` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx come on now

Comment: Isn't just...Prgba64 (but yes, you're right, MSDN description for PixelFormats.Prgba64 wrongly states it's 32 bit per each component).

Comment: @DJKRAZE I _guess_ he did but MSDN is wrong there (PixelFormats class, not PixelFormat enumeration). Error is pretty obvious but he may be confused...

Comment: good catch `Adriano` + 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `PixelFormats.Prgba64`, reading [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats) you may be confused because **there is a small error in documentation**: it states it's 32 bit per channel.

> Prgba64 is a sRGB format with 64 bits per pixel (BPP). **Each channel** (blue, green, red, and alpha) is allocated **32 bits per pixel** (BPP). Each color channel is pre-multiplied by the alpha value. This format has a gamma of 1.0.

It's obviously wrong because 4 channels, each one 32 bits, would result in 128 bits instead of 64. *Corrected* this error then it's equivalent to `PixelFormat.Format64bppPArgb`:

> Specifies that the format is 64 bits per pixel; 16 bits each are used for the alpha, red, green, and blue components. The red, green, and blue components are premultiplied according to the alpha component.